# Get sibling AbstractControl from Angular reactive FormArray - Custom Validation

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-abstract-control, angular-custom-validators

I'm having a Contact form in Angular using a Reactive form. The form contains `firstName`, `lastName` and an Array of `address`. Each address formgroup contains a checkbox, if the checkbox is checked, validation of the State text box mandatory is needed, along with min and max char length.

I have written a custom validator namely "`stateValidator`" and I tried to get the sibling element "`isMandatory`" but I am not able to get the control.

I tried the following approach

- `control.root.get('isMandatory');` - Its returning `null`
- `control.parent.get('isMandatory');` - Its throwing exception

I found some links in stackoverflow, but there is no answer available and some answers are not giving solutions, for example the code above: `control.root.get('isMandatory');` I got this from one of the video tutorials but nothing worked.

The complete working source code is available in StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-validators-in-dynamic-formarray

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, Validators, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  public userForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.userForm = this._fb.group({
      firstName: [],
      lastName: [],
      address: this._fb.array([this.addAddressGroup()])
    });
  }

  private addAddressGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this._fb.group({
      street: [],
      city: [],
      state: ['', this.stateValidator],
      isMandatory: [false, [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  get addressArray(): FormArray {
    return <FormArray>this.userForm.get('address');
  }

  addAddress(): void {
    this.addressArray.push(this.addAddressGroup());
  }

  removeAddress(index: number): void {
    this.addressArray.removeAt(index);
  }

  stateValidator(control: AbstractControl): any {
        if(typeof control === 'undefined' || control === null 
        || typeof control.value === 'undefined' || control.value === null) {
            return {
                required: true
            }
        }

        const stateName: string = control.value.trim();
        const isPrimaryControl: AbstractControl = control.root.get('isMandatory');

        console.log(isPrimaryControl)

        if(typeof isPrimaryControl === 'undefined' || isPrimaryControl === null||
        typeof isPrimaryControl.value === 'undefined' || isPrimaryControl.value === null) {
            return {
                invalidFlag: true
            }
        }

        const isPrimary: boolean = isPrimaryControl.value;

        if(isPrimary === true) {
            if(stateName.length < 3) {
                return {
                    minLength: true
                };
            } else if(stateName.length > 50) {
                return {
                    maxLength: true
                };
            }
        } else {
            control.setValue('');
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="userForm">
  <div>
    <mat-card class="example-card">
      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>Users Creation</mat-card-title>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
        <div class="primary-container">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="First Name" value="" formControlName="firstName">
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Last Name" value="" formControlName="lastName">
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div formArrayName="address">
          <div class="address-container" *ngFor="let group of addressArray.controls; let i = index;"
            [formGroupName]="i">
            <fieldset>
              <legend>
                <h3>Address: {{i + 1}}</h3>
              </legend>
              <mat-checkbox formControlName="isMandatory">Mandatory</mat-checkbox>
              <div>
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput placeholder="Street" value="" formControlName="street">
                </mat-form-field>
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput placeholder="City" value="" formControlName="city">
                </mat-form-field>
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput placeholder="State" value="" formControlName="state">
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row org-desc-parent-margin">
          <button mat-raised-button (click)="addAddress()">Add more address</button>
        </div>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</form>
<mat-card class="pre-code">
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>Users Information</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <pre>{{userForm.value | json}}</pre>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Kindly assist me how to get the sibling abstract control in the custom validator method.

I tried the code which was specified in the following couple of answers

```
isPrimaryControl = (<FormGroup>control.parent).get('isMandatory')
```

It's throwing an error `ERROR Error: too much recursion`. Kindly assist me how to fix this.

Comment: If you have to put validations which include multiple formControls, consider adding the Validator to the formGroup instead of a single formControl.

Comment: @SachinGupta - My primary aim of this question is how to get the sibling control over another control.

Comment: As stated in my answer, you can use `(<FormGroup>control.parent).get('isMandatory')`. However, depending on where you access `control.parent`, there might be a chance that the value is `undefined` so you have to put proper checks

Comment: I'm getting an error `ERROR Error: too much recursion` if I add the code `isPrimaryControl = (<FormGroup>control.parent).get('isMandatory')`

Comment: @SachinGupta If its possible try the code in the said StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-validators-in-dynamic-formarray

Comment: comment the `control.setValue('')`

Comment: @SachinGupta - Its working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to cast the parent to `FormGroup`, try using :

```
if(control.parent) {
    (<FormGroup>control.parent).get('isMandatory')
}
```

Comment: Its giving an console error `ERROR Error: control.parent is undefined`

Comment: I tried in the chrome console with a debugger in stateValidator function, it gave the parent group and I was also able to get the isMandatory control.

Comment: could you please see the code in StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-validators-in-dynamic-formarray

Comment: Seen now. When the control is created, it is not attached to a parent, hence you will get the error. Just put a `if (control.parent)` check and everything else should work fine.

Comment: Forked your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-validators-in-dynamic-formarray-tjvagn You need to comment the `control.setValue('')` or you will not be able to type anything in control. Some minor tweaking on click of checkbox might be needed for proper validation.

Comment: Could you please give the complete solution, that what actually I missed and needs to do to achieve. What about if `control.parent` is `undefined` ? Moreover it's not validating if the checkbox is checked. I think its not triggering the custom validator method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191643/discussion-between-sachin-gupta-and-b-balamanigandan).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of `isMandatory` from Form control like this, i have changed your `stateValidator` method to basically typecast the `control` to concrete sub class then from the `controls` array you can get the `formControls`

```
stateValidator(control: AbstractControl): any {
let mandatory:boolean=false;
if(control.parent){
  console.log('control',<FormGroup>control.parent.controls.isMandatory.value);
  mandatory=<FormGroup>control.parent.controls.isMandatory.value;
}
    if((typeof control === 'undefined' || control === null 
    || typeof control.value === 'undefined' || control.value === null)&& mandatory) {
      debugger;
        return {
            required: true
        }
    }

    const stateName: string = control.value.trim();
    let isPrimaryControl: AbstractControl=null;
    if(control.parent){
     isPrimaryControl=<FormGroup>control.parent.controls.isMandatory;
    console.log(isPrimaryControl)
    }
    if(typeof isPrimaryControl === 'undefined' || isPrimaryControl === null||typeof isPrimaryControl.value === 'undefined' || isPrimaryControl.value === null) {
        return {
            invalidFlag: true
        }
    }

    const isPrimary: boolean = isPrimaryControl.value;

    if(isPrimary === true) {
        if(stateName.length < 3) {
            return {
                minLength: true
            };
        } else if(stateName.length > 50) {
            return {
                maxLength: true
            };
        }
    } else {
        control.setValue('');
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I think its crashing the page if I use `control.parent.controls` (i.e., In actual application it throws an exception)

Comment: What’s the exception it’s throwing?

Comment: Try your code in the following StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-validators-in-dynamic-formarray it will crash the window.

Comment: I'm getting the error `ERROR Error: too much recursion`